# TrendMicro Deep Security 11 - retrieving computers in "protected" state in terms of antimalware

Tags: api, deepsecurity, antimalware

Does anyone know if total number of anti-malware protected computers can be retrieved by API or any other way "by script". In DSM there's widget "anti-malware protection status" and we have "anti-malware report" in scheduled task which both return correct number of protected/unprotected/not capable machines in terms of anti-malware module.

In API documentation I found object HostStatusSummaryTransport which has some properties that return number of critical hosts, locked, online, unmanaged or warning, however there's no property for "protected" in antimalware terms.

Another object HostStatusTransport has overallantimalwarestatus, but it's object that represents singular computer integrated with DSM. With smaller environment it would be viable to do loop for all computers and count all "OK" statuses, however we have more than 1000 machines protected and script would execute for several hours...

Do you know any methods to retrieve this number fast? Both widget and report can obtain these values relatively quick.